# How to correctly send/receive Unicode in XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, apache, unicode

I am trying to send a string containing the `·` character to the server using XMLHttpRequest.  I am using the following code to set the content type in my javascript code:

```
xmlhttpreq.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")
```

Now if I look up what the actual UTF-8 value for `·`, e.g. using a page like [this one](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=%C2%B7&mode=char) or [this one](http://unicodelookup.com/), it tells me the value should be 183, or 0xC2 0xB7 as UTF-8 hex bytes.  I see the latter being sent to the server.  The server, when it returns this data encodes it as the string "\u00C2\u00B7", or the literal bytes 0x5C 0x75 0x30 0x30 0x43 0x32 0x5C 0x75 0x30 0x30 0x42 0x37.  The response is passed to `JSON.parse(xmlhttpreq.responseText)` which converts this to `Â·`.  Where did the extra `Â` come from?

The page is UTF-8, the XMLHttpRequest is UTF-8, document.codeset is UTF-8, and the server response is UTF-8.

Comment: `·` is one *character*, so of course it's only one character (and the string `"·"` has no second character)! But that doesn't tell you how many bytes it takes up.

Comment: @immibis Right, but I was reading that certain unicode character (above 0x10000 I think) require you call charCodeAt(1) to get the high part of the code.

Comment: `charCodeAt()` returns UTF-16 shorts, so you would only see one value for anything that’s only encoded as two bytes in UTF-16 (which `·` is). The correct way to handle this is to make all parts accept UTF-8.

Comment: @RyanO'Hara Right, but shouldn't setting the code page to UTF-8 (`<meta charset="UTF-8">` in the page originally served, and `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "...; charset=UTF-8");` in the XMLHttpRequest be sufficient to do that?  Even with both those measures, I'm still seeing the browser encode the character as `%C2%B7` instead of just `%B7`.  I don't understand why the extra `%C2`.

Comment: @Michael: `%C2%B7` is the correct UTF-8, and you also have to make sure you’re actually writing UTF-8 as output. Try finding which point is breaking things by changing your server to write back a fixed UTF-8 string first.

Comment: Be sure to use `encodeURIComponent` instead of `escape`, too.

Comment: Wouldn't encodeURIComponent will give you `%C2%B7`, which is not what OP wants

Comment: @Musa: OP *should* want the correct encoding :)

Comment: I should also note that `escape` doesn't work right either, because XMLHttpRequest is *already* escaping things like space, so escaping the string before passing to send() results in things like `%25%20` instead of `%20` which totally confuses the server!

Comment: @RyanO'Hara I would love the correct encoding, if I could just figure out how to get it to work!

Comment: That sounds unusual. Could you show some code? Also, assuming that the test for outputting some fixed UTF-8-encoded text works, make sure whatever’s responsible for decoding request parameters is interpreting as and producing UTF-8.

Comment: @RyanO'Hara XMLHttpRequest is using content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which I think is why it is already generating the `%C2%B7` ... but I think this is not the correct encoding, because if I try setting a Javascript string to that, I get `Â·` instead of `·`

Comment: @Michael: As the answer has been deleted, I update yopur knowledge here: using 8 bits, does not mean all codes are actually ASCII (read the posted paragraph carefully!). Some machines even ignored the MSbit or used it to e.g. add blinking/highlight, etc. If they used that bit to switch between two code-pages, does not change the fact that ASCII is only 7 bits. Note that UTF-8 does exactly the same: used the 8th bit to signal non-ASCII encoding.

Comment: @Olaf I am updating the question substantially to reflect the conversation.

Comment: @Michael: How did you try “setting a JavaScript string to that”? `decodeURIComponent('%C2%B7') === '·'`.

Comment: @RyanO'Hara The server returns the string "\xc2\xb7" which automatically gets rendered as `Â·` which no decoding required.

Comment: The WP entry is somewhat incomplete. With introduction of the Euro (`€`), ISO-LATIN-15 became more relevant than -1. In general, iff(!) one has to use ISO-8859, for western languages, -15 is the better choice.

Comment: @Michael: Automatically gets rendered as `Â·` by what? Does `"\xc2\xb7"` represent the two bytes `c2 b7` or is it a JavaScript string literal representing the four bytes `c3 82 c2 b7`? Check things with `curl`.

Comment: @RyanO'Hara It's actually returning the string literally as: `"\u00C2\u00B7"`, or 0x5C 0x75 0x30 0x30 0x43 0x32 0x5C 0x75 0x30 0x30 0x42 0x37.

Comment: @Michael: *Please* show your code.

Comment: @RyanO'Hara What code do you want me to show? I've included everything I think is relevant.

Comment: @Michael: Chat might be better at this point: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102419/question-35167234

Comment: @RyanO'Hara Ok, I've finially finished updating the question to hopefully contain only/all the relevant info.

Comment: Okay, the JSON is wrong. Your server should be producing `"\u00b7"`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102420/discussion-between-michael-and-ryan-ohara).

Comment: `"\u00C2\u00B7"` and `"Â·"` (they are equivalent in JSON) is what you get if you encode **·** as UTF-8 and then decode it as Windows-1252. So I'd say your server might be treating that data as Windows-1252 anyway. Please include the code on your server.

Comment: The server side is the problem. It is treating its input as ISO-8859-1, not UTF-8. What is the application/language on the server side? Note that setting the `charset` parameter has no effect as the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` MIME type has no such parameter.

Answer (score -2):

It's a problem about URL encoding, not text encoding. Please read this:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

You must do the URL decoding in your pure C CGI.

Answer (score -2):

Per discussion with Ryan O'Hara in chat, the issue is that JSON is UTF-16, not UTF-8.  Therefore, the server needs to generate a UTF-16 string, which is best accomplished by using a JSON library.  In my case I used this simple jansson snippet:

```
json_dumpf(json_string(str),stdout,JSON_ENCODE_ANY);
```

Comment: Um no, JSON can also be encoded with UTF-8. At least Wikipedia and Facebook will send JSON files in that encoding.

Comment: And, of course, StackOverflow. You can go to https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers, click on the [example URL](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers?pagesize=1&order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow) and verify that the response is in fact encoded as UTF-8